# How to Change Label of TabHost Programmatically/Dynamically

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I have a tabhost created by

```
  this.tabHost = getTabHost();

     // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch the first Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, FirstGroup.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for the first tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("FirstGroup").setIndicator("Regionlar",
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.region2)) // Replace null with R.drawable.your_icon to set tab icon
                    .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec1);
```

And I want to change label of tabhost programmatically: "Regionlar" to "newMenuTabbar". I couldn't find any example. thanks for attention.

Edit:
I want to change second tabitem's label from "Mənzərələr"=> "secondTabitem"

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, FirstGroup.class);

```
    // Initialize a TabSpec for the first tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("FirstGroup").setIndicator("Regionlar",
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.region2)) // Replace null with R.drawable.your_icon to set tab icon
                    .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec1);

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SecondActivityGroup.class);
    spec2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("SecondActivityGroup").setIndicator("Mənzərələr",
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img_gallery_icon)) // Replace null with R.drawable.your_icon to set tab icon
                    .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec2);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
final TextView label = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().findViewById(android.R.id.title);
label .setText(YOUR NEW LABEL);
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: what about to change second tabitem's label? I've edited the question.

Comment: I have solved anyway: 
 final TextView label = (TextView) tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
     label .setText("newTabmenu");

You can change each label of tabitem iterating with getchildat(i) method.

Comment: Yes, you can get the index of each tab by: 
final int k = tabHost.getCurrentTab();

Answer (score 1):

b.i 's code can only change the first tab's title. 
I think this is a more straight way to get the thing done:

```
((TextView) mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(position)
.findViewById(android.R.id.title))
.setText(yourTitle);
```

where `position` is the position of the tab and `yourTitle` is the title you wish to set for the tab. If you want to change the text for the current tab, then instead of replacing `position` by `getCurrentTab`, you can just replace `getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(position)`
by `getCurrentTabView()`

Whoever wrote this should have defined a `setTabText(int position, String text)` method, otherwise who would know they have a text view id'ed `android.R.id.title`? Or if they already had, please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public class SlideMainActivity extends TabActivity {
    public static RelativeLayout headerLayout;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_silde_tab);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
                R.layout.hd_header);
        setTabs();
    }

    private void setTabs() {
        addTab("FirstGroup", R.drawable.tab_home, FirstGroup.class);
        addTab("Regionlar", R.drawable.tab_search, Regionlar.class);

    }

    private void addTab(String labelId, int drawableId, Class<?> c) {
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId);

        View tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
        TextView title = (TextView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(labelId);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        icon.setImageResource(drawableId);

        spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);
    }

}
```